# Force line break on mobile - currently it breaks word in half

Tags: html, css

We’ve recently updated our website. Newer look better forms etc.
However with the new design there is one issues I can’t solve:

Headlines are not getting displayed properly on mobile. And by properly I mean the line break happens in the middle of a word like: 
"Content Intelligen
e"
Or:
"Managemen
t team”
Or:
"Differentiate
d technolog
y”

Here is a screenshot how it looks on the site: http://prntscr.com/d60i8i

I’ve tried different methods to counteract this but none of them worked.
Here are the details:

**Display: block into display: inline**

```
@media (max-width: 560px) {
.rwd-line {display: block;}
}
@media (min-width: 560px) {
.rwd-line {display: inline;}
}
```

---

**word-break method**

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-word;
```

---

**overflow method**

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

---

This is all I had to try.
For an example you can check this page: http://www.idioplatform.com/about/
You will have several headlines here having this issue on mobile.

Can you please help me trying to solve this?
It feels I’ve sank way more time in this than it deserved but now I am determined to get it corrected somehow.

Any help if much appreciated!

Comment: Using `word-wrap: break-word` is a very wrong approach in your case.

Comment: For better layout, just try to "display:block" the span of each word. Central Intelligence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use in media query:

```
.rwd-line {
 overflow-wrap: unset;
 word-break: unset;
 }
 .rwd-line span {
 display:inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little neat trick for your problem as it seems that everything else doesnt work:
Insert a force line break before word

```
h2 span::before {
content: "\A";
white-space: pre;
}
```